# AngularJS - difference between v1.3.x and v1.4.3 – $interval is changing parameter

Tags: angularjs

I´m using this line of code to call the function $scope.calculateWeekScore and passing $scope.activeWeek as a parameter:

```
$interval($scope.calculateWeekScore, 2000, 0, true, $scope.activeWeek);
```

I´m following $interval documentation:

```
$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

where "[count]" is "Number of times to repeat. If not set, or 0, will repeat indefinitely. (default: 0)"
and
"[Pass]" is "additional parameters to the executed function".

It is calling the function correctly each 2000 miliseconds and the FIRST time it is called, the parameter ($scope.activeWeek) is correct. But after the first call, it resets the parameter to 0 and increments by 1 on each new call.

I´ve looked a hundred times in the function and it doesn´t change its parameter at all.. it is used ONLY on this IF as "chosenWeek" (I won´t post the function here because it is kinda large):

```
if ($scope.allGames[i].Week == chosenWeek)
```

So I can only assume $interval is messing with the parameter.. am I doing something wrong at the "[count]" or anything else?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just tested with [count] = 10..
It resets my parameter and increments from 0 to 9, then stops calling it.
So it is for sure that the count is changing my parameter... but why? And how can I stop it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/noRPObGXUjiWSSdqCkvA?p=preview
It messes with the parameter only when printed with the console.log.. you get to see it increment along with each function call.

Comment: Something must be missing from the information you provided. [Here's a plunkr using $interval](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsKitcelyVbZuVKtXFlo?p=preview) which doesn't exhibit this behaviour. Can you recreate this phenomenon in a plunkr? (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), preferably)

Comment: I'm more tempted to assume the big unseen function is messing something up rather than `$interval()`, angular is pretty solid. Have you try to isolate your assumption? Something simple like `$interval(function(n) { console.log(n) }, 2000, 0, true, 1);` should be enough to see the error if `$interval` is indeed messing with the value.

Comment: Just created a function onTime with this:  function onTime (parameter)
 {
  console.log(parameter);
 }

And it is messing with the parameter.

Comment: Also, @gillesc your example is messing with the value just like the way it is messing with my parameter!

Comment: I´ve created the plunkr and the results are..awkward. Either on the plunkr and on my code, It doesn´t change the parameter when used on the html. it only changes when printed on the console log.. If you manage to see the console log, you´ll see the $interval messing with the parameter: http://plnkr.co/edit/noRPObGXUjiWSSdqCkvA?p=preview

Comment: Found it.
I was using AngularJS v1.3.. I updated for 1.4 and it stopped messing with my parameter. (And it is working properly on my plunkr example as well)

Comment: Ah yes that feature is only available from 1.4 [4f1f9cfd](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4f1f9cfdb721cf308ca1162b2227836dc1d28388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]); is only applicable to angular 1.4+. Make sure you are includingthe right version.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.. Thanks!